# Problem with TeamCity plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, teamcity

The problem is this:  The "Remote Run" option is always grayed out.  Anybody know how to fix this?  I have made changes to two files, and want to run them, but the plugin won't let me.  The same things works fine in IntelliJ, but I really prefer Eclipse, and I'd like to get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this to be highly dependent on my versions of Teamcity, Eclipse and Subclipse. Currently, I use TC 4.0.1 and my remote run does not work in Eclipse 3.4. However, the same plugin worked fine for me in Eclipse 3.3 and an earlier version of Subclipse.

Your best bet would be to post this info on the [Jetbrains Tracker](http://jetbrains.net/tracker) if you haven't already and see if a developer can take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I've submitted the problem, and we'll see where that goes.